# journalctl set default datetime format

Tags: systemd, journalctl

How can I configure the journalctl output to use a specified date format?

I know I can parse out the line and convert to a date format, but I'm hoping to see the log lines with the ISO format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-o` option allows the timestamp formatting to be chosen among a few options, including ISO format (*e.g.* `2022-08-04T17:45:08+0200`) with

```
journalctl -o short-iso
```

or

```
journalctl -o short-iso-precise
```

if you need milliseconds.